# The append() method issue of list in Python3

Tags: python, list, append

for example,i got a list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

we all know append() can add a new item at the end of the list like that:

```
mylist.append(4)
```

now the mylist is [1,2,3,4]

my issue is what happened when mylist append itself????

```
mylist.append(mylist)
```

at first i think it will look like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]
```

but when i print it, output is [1,2,3,4,[...]],so i print the mylist[5] and it's same to the mylist:[1,2,3,4,[...]]

so you can loop the last item of list endless,and the last item always be the same to original mylist!!!!!

anyone can tell me why is that????????

Comment: ... because that's what you _told_ it to do. `...` is shorthand for "this is a copy of myself, and it can't be printed because we'd be here all day."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you aren't appending a *copy* of the list, but the actual list object itself. Consider this program:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist.append(mylist)
assert id(mylist) == id(mylist[4])
```

The final item of the list is a reference to the list itself, so you have a fully recursive, self-referential data structure.

If you want the result `[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]`, then you need to append a copy of the original list, like so:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
mylist.append(list(mylist))
assert mylist == [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]
```

Comment: thanks，i think that the reason. i usually use Swift to develop and that issue not same at Swift

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because you're telling Python to append a list(`my_list`) to a list. If you want to extend the list with the contents of the list, you can do this:

```
new_list = old_list + new_list
output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or you can use the `extend` method.

```
old_list.extend(my_list)
```

Which will modify the old_list in place.